# Caching request responses

Tags: javascript, http, caching

Should I cache all request responses myself in a local storage, and update the cache when it's necessary after specific user actions?

I would for example cache a response returning a list of something, and change the cache after a user relogs, adds something, edits, deletes, etc.

Is this a good approach? I know there's something like a HTTP cache, but it seems that my requests are not cached by default, or that I don't have full control over it.

Comment: Could you provide some context? Are you using a specific framework, for example? Or do you mean browser cache?

Comment: I mean browser cache, with clean JS.